# Convergence of series, comparison test on $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}+ \ln n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I am suppose to use the limit comparison test to prove divergence or convergence. There isn't really any examples in my book that show how to pick your $b_n$ so I just pick whatever works out nicely.

$$a_n = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n} + \ln n}$$

$$b_n = \dfrac{1}{n^4}$$

I chose this because I know that it converges and that it makes the math easier.

$$\dfrac {\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n} + \ln n}}{\dfrac{1}{n^4}}$$

$$ {\dfrac{n^4}{\sqrt{n} + \ln n}}$$

So now I look at my Table of Truths to find the answer.

I know that my $b_n$ converges, that is easy. It goes to zero.

My $a_n$ I am not sure about. I do know that the limit of $\dfrac{a_n}{b_n}$ is greater than zero.

According to the table it converges if $b_n$ does, but infinity is another option so I guess that this is really infinity which is only converges if $a_n$ does. So now I need to look at $a_n$ but really isn't an infinite limit > 0? Besides that logical confusion $a_n$ does converge to zero so that means $b_n$ converges as well. Which I guess is kind of confusing to me, because it seems like I didn't really prove anything since I just looked at the original function which I know goes towards zero anyways.

What just happened? I feel like I did nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suggestion:

If you're fairly new to sequences and series, a quick and "dirty" way to show that the series *diverges* (it fails to converge) is to compare it to $b_n = \dfrac 1n.\;$ Recall, the harmonic series diverges: $\sum_{n\to \infty} \frac 1n \to \infty$.

And, you can confirm: $$\forall n \geq 3,\quad \dfrac 1n \leq \dfrac{1}{\sqrt n + \ln n}$$

Comment: So I am suppose to know that logn is less than n and lnn * square root n is still less than n?

Comment: Yes, it sure is: the product is equal to n only for $n = 1$. All you need to know is that $(\ln n) \leq \sqrt n$, since $\sqrt n\cdot \sqrt n = n$, so $\sqrt n\cdot \ln n \leq n$

Comment: Well what if I wanted to actually evaluate this sequence? What is a good $b_n$ to pick and why? Can it by any positive number?

Comment: See this graph, Paul: [square root vs ln](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y+%3D+ln+x%2C+y+%3D+\sqrt+x%2C+x+from+1+to+100)

Comment: Tackle convergence, divergence first. If a series diverges, it diverges to infinity (there's no finite sum to be had!). $b_n = \dfrac 1n$ is a great choice.

Comment: But why is that a good choice? This is what I don't understand, why not pick 1, $\frac{1}{n^4000}$ or anything else?

Comment: Because to show a series diverges (since it does), you want to pick a $b_n$ so that $b_n$ diverges AND $b_n \leq a_n$. The series with the term $\dfrac 1{n^4}$ converges, so doesn't work. The series with the general term $b_n = 1\geq \dfrac 1{\sqrt n + \ln n}$. Convergence of a series can be shown IF $a_n \lt b_n$ and $b_n$ converges. There's no such $b_n$ that will show **this** series converges, because, in fact, it diverges.

Comment: @amWhy: Dirty is equal to divergence, +1

Answer (score 1):

Do you have not noticed that
$$a_n\sim_\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt n}?$$